# Perl save web page from cp1256 into utf-8

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8, arabic

I am trying to save this web page which seems have encoding cp1256 into a text file in UTF-8 encoded format, the problem if I try to replace an html entity before saving & # 1548; by its Arabic char "،" the saved file contents is not Arabic anymore.

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use Encode;
use LWP::Simple;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $url = qq{https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=7&tSoraNo=1&tAyahNo=1&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1};
my $content = get($url);

$content = decode('cp1256', $content);

my $ch = chr(0x60c);
# this line causes the problem
$content =~ s/\&#1548\;/$ch/mg;

open File, ">filecontent.txt" or die "Error creating file.\n";
binmode File, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
print File $content;
close File;

exit;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to decode that page from CP1251 (which is a Cyrillic codepage). The HTTP headers and the `META HTTP-EQUIV` element both agree that it's encoded in CP1256 (which makes more sense, as that's an Arabic codepage).

Comment: @DaveCross Assuming it is as you said CP1256 I need to convert it and save it as UTF-8, this is what I need. I need to save it to mysql table in UTF-8.

Comment: Sure. But why were you using CP1251? What made you think it was CP1251? And does anything change if you use CP1256 instead?

Comment: @DaveCross I was trying nothing more I was wrong but now I used online website to detect encoding and it confirmed your suggestion as cp1256. But still same problem. I need to convert it to UTF-8 to save it to mysql table and also replace the html entity with its arabic unicode as in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `decoded_content` in [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) instead, it uses the Content-Type header.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
require LWP::Protocol::https;
my $url = 'https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp'
    . '?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=7&tSoraNo=1&tAyahNo=1'
    . '&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get($url);
if ($response->is_success) {
    my $content = $response->decoded_content;
    $content =~ s/&#1548;/\N{ARABIC COMMA}/g;
    open my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'filecontent.html';
    $fh->print($content);
} else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Comment: That did it in clean way.